# Is there any way to upload large files to Firebase Storage using Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload large files to Firebase Storage using expo, so far nothing is working. I am using fetch to create blob to upload files but this is not working for large files over 800 MB size. I also couldn't find any stream upload method for expo. Is there any optimised way I could upload large files to Firebase Storage?

Comment: I'm interested in the same. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @schneikai i didn't find any solutions, in the end i build the app using Android Studio java.